# Ruby array of hashes organized into an irregular html table

Tags: ruby, html-table, sinatra

I'm trying generate an HTML table using data from a json array in ruby which currently contains 5 hashes (might go up to 20 hashes). Each hash has 30+ fields (date, cost, etc). I can do it by hand but coding it would definitely be more elegant.

The HTML table is irregular. First column is the header which will be the hash key (for example "date" or "cost"), the  fields to the right of the header column would be a loop going through the hashes and getting the corresponding value. Closest thing that comes to mind is a financial statement, here's an example: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Pseudo code of final HTML output result would be something like this (based on json array example below):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <td>2021-07-01</td>
    <td>2021-07-02</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Component Number</th>
    <td>ABC123</td>
    <td>XYZ789</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>5.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The json structure looks like this (limited to only 2 hashes here, but could be as many as 20). I currently have an instance variable `@cf` using httParty to get the json array.

```
[ {
  "date": "2021-07-01",
  "componentNumber": "ABC123",
  "cost": "1.0",
  "other": "test"
}, {
  "date": "2021-07-02",
  "componentNumber": "XYZ789",
  "cost": "5.0",
  "other": "test"
} ]
```

If you need any more info, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given your variable `@cf` containing the hash, you can built a table in view following this example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Component number</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <% @cf.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= row[:date] %></td>
      <td><%= row[:componentNumber] %></td>
      <td><%= row[:cost] %></td>
      <td><%= row[:other] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```html
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Component number</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-07-01</td>
      <td>ABC123</td>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2021-07-02</td>
      <td>XYZ789</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

#### For a transposed table

In case you need a transposed layout, you could adjust the data in controller generating a transposet table (array) from the original hash, for example:

```
tmp = @cf.map { |h| h.values }
headers = ['Date', 'Component number', 'Cost', 'Other']
@transposed_with_headers = tmp.prepend(headers).transpose
```

This returns the following data structure:

```
#=> [["Date", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-02"], ["Component number", "ABC123", "XYZ789"], ["Cost", "1.0", "5.0"], ["Other", "test", "test"]]
```

Finally use `@transposed_with_headers` in view in this way:

```
<table>
  <% @transposed_with_headers.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="text-align:left"><%= row[0] %></th>
      <% row[1..].each do |content| %>
        <td><%= content %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This generates the following HTML code:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Date</th>
      <td>2021-07-01</td>
      <td>2021-07-02</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Component number</th>
      <td>ABC123</td>
      <td>XYZ789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Cost</th>
      <td>1.0</td>
      <td>5.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" style="text-align:left">Other</th>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but not the solution I need. In my case I need the table header to be the first column (not the first row) and the fields to the right of the header column would be a loop going through the hashes and getting the corresponding value. As shown in my pseudo code. Would you know how to do it that way?

Comment: @slythic, I edited to get the transposed table.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not optimal but I ended up using the following pseudo code:

```
<table>
  <% @cf.first.each_with_index do |x,i| #loop through count of first hash, all hashes have same count in my case%>
  <tr>
    <th><%= fieldName %></th>
    
    <% @cf.each do |y| #loop the fields %>
    <td><%= y.values[i] %></td>

   ...
```

Hope this helps someone looking for this particular issue. If you have a better solution, I'd love to hear it!